# Error creating bean with name '***.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite in the Spring Boot application.
But the application cannot create the bean below.

> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration

What should I do?
I searched the relevant issues on this site, but could not find an appropriate one.

The `pom.xml` is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.4.RELEASE
 

com.luminous.spring
rest
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
rest
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.31.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the `application.properties` is as below.

```
    spring.jpa.database-platform=com.luminous.spring.dialect.SQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:employee.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin
```

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace when you ask questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered similar question many times in last week. Here's one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070391/607637

---

You are overriding the hibernate to use very very old version that is not compatible with the version of Spring Boot that you are using. I belive that's the reason why you are getting the error.

Since you are already using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, you really don't need to define the following artifacts. Just delete them.

- spring-boot-starter-jdbc
- javax.persistence
- hibernate-entitymanager
- hibernate-validator
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat
- sqlite-jdbc

Your pom.xml will be simple as following: Note you don't need to override any version and no need.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi gtiwari. Thank you for your comment. But the error persists.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource'

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.sqlite.JDBC in either of HikariConfig class

Comment: How can I specify the JDBC Class for SQLite?

Comment: Share your code. You didn't even shared the stacktrace.